# How to check when HealthKit function has been completed (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, function, healthkit, completionhandler

Well, the title really says it all, and I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere that works for me so I am turning to StackOverFlow. I am trying to get a users step count and assign that value to a UILabel. So here is some of my code (please note that this function is contained in another class as a result the label is **not** within the scope of this function):

```
func readTodayHealthData() -> Int {
        var stepCount: Int = 0
        func getStepsHealthData() {
        let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
        let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum
        let stepsHealthDataQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsHealth, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: sumOption) {
            query, results, error in
            if let sumQuantity = results?.sumQuantity() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    stepCount = sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit) * 2
                })
            }
        }
        healthKitStore?.executeQuery(stepsHealthDataQuery)
    }
  return stepCount
}
//Set UILabel Value
//**This code is in my View Controller which is in a separate class as a result this label is NOT within the scope of this function.**
myLabel.text = String(readTodayHealthData)
```

Then when I run the app on an actual device I see the label text is zero, and I know for a fact that I have done some walking today :). So, I think the issue is that when I try to set the labels value the function hasn't fully finished executing.

I know this because when I use the [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/5266082) function and wait for two seconds I end up getting a value, but if I don't wait then I get a value of zero.

So the main question is: **How do I check when a function is *completely* finished executing?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that the operation you're using is async, then you need to handle properly, you have two options here:

1. Update the `UILabel` in the `completionHandler` inside your function `getStepsHealthData` in the main thread because you are going to update the UI, like in this way:

   ```
   func getStepsHealthData() {
        var stepCount: Int = 0
        let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
        let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum

        let stepsHealthDataQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsHealth, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: sumOption) {
           query, results, error in
             if let sumQuantity = results?.sumQuantity() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                  stepCount = sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit) * 2

                  //Set UILabel Value
                  myLabel.text = String(stepCount)
                })
             }
        }
        healthKitStore?.executeQuery(stepsHealthDataQuery)
   }
   ```

   And you don't need to return anything.
2. If you want to return the step counts from the function so you need to play a little with closures and modify your function like in the following way:

   ```
   func getStepsHealthData(completion: (steps: Int) -> ()) {
        var stepCount: Int = 0
        let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
        let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum

        let stepsHealthDataQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsHealth, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: sumOption) {
           query, results, error in
             if let sumQuantity = results?.sumQuantity() {
                 stepCount = sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit) * 2
                 completion(stepCount)
             }
        }
        healthKitStore?.executeQuery(stepsHealthDataQuery)
   }
   ```

   And then you can call it like in this way from outside:

   ```
   self.getStepsHealthData() { (steps) -> Void in
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          //Set UILabel Value
          myLabel.text = String(stepCount)
      })
   }
   ```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The completion handlers (which you're already using) are called when the data is available. `readTodayHealthData()` will return well before that happens.

You need to use the data within the scope of the completion handler. For example, you could rewrite your function like this:

```
func updateLabel() {
        var stepCount: Int = 0
        func getStepsHealthData() {
        let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
        let sumOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum
        let stepsHealthDataQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsHealth, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: sumOption) {
            query, results, error in
            if let sumQuantity = results?.sumQuantity() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    stepCount = sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit) * 2
                    self.myLabel.text = "\(stepCount)"
                })
            }
        }
        healthKitStore?.executeQuery(stepsHealthDataQuery)
    }
}
```

This will update the label when the data has been returned.

Comment: Ok, let me update my question the label is **not** in the scope of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually trying to check if a function has finished executing though. That block that you pass to HKStatisticsQuery isn't really part of your original function. If you really want to prevent the `myLabel.text=` line from executing until after the block is called, you could use a [semaphore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html), but that's a terrible solution to your actual problem. Why not have your block that's passed to HK update the label directly?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    stepCount = sumQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit) * 2
                    myLabel.text = "\(stepCount)"
                })
```

Comment: Ok, let me update my question the label is **not** in the scope of the function.

Comment: Regardless of the scope of the label, you need to understand the concept of blocks and why your function returns without the `stepCount` being set. Read the [docs from Apple on blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) and you'll know exactly why this is happening and how to address it.